# time since midnight

Tags: java, time

I am using a Java library that has a method that wants a time info.
it is described like this:

```
public void function(byte[] time);
```

> time: The time is provided in 1/100th seconds since midnight as a three bytes integer, starting with the most significant byte.

I don't know how to do that. I can get time in `milliseconds(Sysem.currentTimeInMillisecond)`. but that gives me milliseconds past since 1 January 1970.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I have just written. I think it is self explainable enough. The logic of converting int to byte array is stolen from `DataOutputStream.writeInt()`

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); //now

    Calendar m = Calendar.getInstance(); //midnight
    m.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    m.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    m.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    m.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    int diff = (int) (c.getTimeInMillis() - m.getTimeInMillis()) ;
    int v = diff / 10;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte) ((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    bytes[1] = (byte) ((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    bytes[2] = (byte) ((v >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    bytes[4] = (byte) ((v >>>  0) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
)
.get( ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY )  
/ 10L
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

Time zone is crucial in determining the current date and time-of-day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Get first moment of that day.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfToday = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate the elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( startOfToday , now ) ;
```

Get the number of milliseconds in that total span of time.

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;
```

But you want 1/100th of a second granularity, not the 1/1,000th of a second that is milliseconds. So divide by ten.

```
long countOfOneHundrethsOfASecondSinceStartOfDay = ( millis / 10L ) ;
```

A shortcut would be to access the `MILLI_OF_DAY` field of the `ZonedDateTime` object, obviating the need to get the start of day.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
long millis = now.get( ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY ) ; 
long countOfOneHundrethsOfASecondSinceStartOfDay = ( millis / 10L ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Gregorian Calendar for now. Clone it and set the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero. Get milliseconds from both and find the difference, then convert to hundredths.